# How do I name a file with looping raster's name?

Tags: arcpy

I'm using arcpy and i need to save a raster file with the looping raster's name inside the output's name, in other words, if the looping raster is named "20170823" it must save like "Example_20170823". 
I need to find something similar to 'Example_%20170823%' that we have in arcgis.

```
import arcpy
import os
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *



rasters = arcpy.ListRasters("*", "TIF")
arcpy.env.workspace = 'Z:\\04 - Temp\\Charles\\NDVI_tempo\\NAL'   

for tiff in rasters: #the loop

    arcpy.MakeRasterLayer_management(tiff, "Z:\\04 - Temp\\Charles\\NDVI_tempo\\NAL\\temp_rast1.tif", "", "", "3")
    arcpy.MakeRasterLayer_management(tiff, "Z:\\04 - Temp\\Charles\\NDVI_tempo\\NAL\\temp_rast2.tif", "", "", "4")

    arcpy.CopyRaster_management("Z:\\04 - Temp\\Charles\\NDVI_tempo\\NAL\\temp_rast1.tif", "copy_rast1", "","", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "")
    arcpy.CopyRaster_management("Z:\\04 - Temp\\Charles\\NDVI_tempo\\NAL\\temp_rast2.tif", "copy_rast2", "","", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "")

    Property1Result = arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management ("copy_rast1", "MINIMUM")
    Property2Result = arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management ("copy_rast2", "MINIMUM")

    Property1 = Property1Result.getOutput
    Property2 = Property2Result.getOutput

    Correcao1 = Minus ("copy_rast1", "Property1")
    Correcao2 = Minus ("copy_rast2", "Property2")

    Rastdiv1 = Minus ("Correcao2", "Correcao1")
    Rastdiv2 = Plus  ("Correcao2", "Correcao1")

    NDVI_tiff = Divide (Rastdiv1, Rastdiv2,'Z:\\04 - Temp\\Charles\\NDVI_tempo\\NAL_PL\\teste\\NDVI_%tiff%.tif') # here the name to replace %tiff%
```

The NDVI_%tiff% must take the information of the tiff's name to add in the final output file's name .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to use is the [Describe](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-functions/describe.htm) function. This is module that can be used to find various metadata about the dataset, including its name.

Use the following to find the name:

```
tiff_name = arcpy.Describe(tiff).name
```

In addition, if you want to append this to an output file name, please look at the [python string operations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html) help.

To append the name, use the following code, and use the variable in your geoprocessing function.

```
output_name = "{}_{}".format("Example", tiff_name)
```